# Change the subversion commit location for a copied project in android studio

Tags: android-studio, svn

I have a project which i have copied from a different completed project,and refactored the package name. after the refactoring and sync was complete android studio asked me whether i wanted to add the newly created files to subversion. i remembered that my previous project was shared through subversion. so i went ahead and disabled the vcs integration for my current project to prevent any accidental modification to my previous project. but now whenever i enable vcs integration on my current project, i am not able to share it as a new project through subversion. i think android studio is holding onto the url of the previous project. so my question is how can i change this? i want to share my newly created project as a new one through subversion. how can it be done?

i remember when i used eclipse, i was used to deleting the CVS directories from my newly created projects which are copied from other ones, and it worked flawlessly. is there any way like this with android studio?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer eventually. the trick was to delete the .svn directory hidden in the root folder of my project. deleting that directory gave the prefect result. and i was able to share my project as a new one through subversion.